# Exclude specific words and sites from Google Search

Tags: google-search

I googled some random keywords and gave me results like this:

[image: I don't want Planetlagu]

I know that `planetlagu.site` is either a song download site or a Youtube download site. They offer MP3, MP4, and 3GP but all of them are unwanted because they contain a lot of junk.

I also receive a lot of unwanted Wikipedia results ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t16Wd.jpg)) and a lot of results from Facebook ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGQXZ.jpg)) which also contains information I don't want.

How can I exclude Facebook, Wikipedia, MP3, MP4, and 3GP pages from a Google Search so that they don't show up in the search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use search operators to remove phrases or sites. For example, to have search results display *without* the word **MP4** in the results, use the search phrase `-MP4`.

To exclude a site such as facebook, use the search phrase `-site:facebook.com`.

A combination of these can help to narrow your search results based on what you need.

> **Exclude words from your search**
>
> Put - in front of a word you want to leave out. For example, jaguar speed -car
>
> **Search for an exact match**
>
> Put a word or phrase inside quotes. For example, "tallest building".
>
> **Search for wildcards or unknown words**
>
> Put a * in your word or phrase where you want to leave a placeholder. For example, "largest * in the world".
>
> **Combine searches**
>
> Put "OR" between each search query. For example,  marathon OR race.
>
> **Search for a specific site**
>
> Put "site:" in front of a site or domain. For example, site:youtube.com or site:.gov.

Sources: [Google Search Help > Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)

Comment: @pnuts I couldn't find a question on webapps that actually answers the question. If the google-search tag is enough, would this topic be closed? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For googling in Google Images Search here's a tip: If I don't want some unrelated and offensive keywords to be appeared on Google Image Search, I had just to negate them. So in many case I had to add -ular -pati -selena -bieber to any keyword I entered (I often saw that those keywords sometimes appear on when I looked for some girl's photo using Google Image Search).